# The roots of quintic polynomial

Tags: newton-raphson, quintics

I have some region $[a,b],$ and  the  polynomial $P(x)$ in it $(\deg P(x)=5)$: Given these conditions

1. $P(a)\cdot P(b)\lt0$
2. $P'(x)\gt 0$ or $P'(x)\lt 0$ when $x\in (a,b)$
3. $P'(a) = P'(b) = 0$

I know that in these conditions there is only one root in the region [a,b], and I can find the root with the Bisection method. But I know that these method is very slow and I want to use Newton's method. I want to find some x0 initial point for the Newton's method, for which the method will always converges to the root.

Comment: I don't know why do you think whether bisection is slow method?

Comment: @openspace I know that when Newtons method is converges then it is faster than bisection method

Comment: I would recommend looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method if you need fast convergence. Unlike bisection method, no initial point in Newton method cannot guarantee convergence for your problem.

Comment: @VasilyMitch I know that there is conditions for the converging of the method like Kantarovich's theorem

Comment: And I think, that in the regian [a,b] ther is region [x1,x2] where the conditions of this theorem can be true